# routing with django and AngularJS

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I new to AngularJS and trying to set up Django with AngularJs, however, I have some issues with handling the routing with those two frameworks. so far I've set up like below:

When I run `http://localhost:8000/index.html` it works and shows me the file, but when I run `http://localhost:8000/test` as I wrote in `app.js` it gives me standard Django 404 error.

What am I missing?

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index.html/$', 
]
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/test", {
        templateUrl : "index.html",
        controller: "MainCtrl"
    })
});

app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "test";
});
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        test
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/general/angular.min.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/app.js' %}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the URL and it's corresponding views method.

In you urls.py
You need something like:

```
url(r'^test/$', views.test, name='test')
```

In views.py

```
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse('You are looking at test')
```